# Can't use new ecmascript decorators in typescript 2.4.2

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is my code example:

```
function enumerable(value: boolean) {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    descriptor.enumerable = value;
  };
}

class A {
  @enumerable(false)
  a: number = 1
  b: number = 2

  myMethod () {}
}

const a = new A()
```

Whatever I try I get:

```
D:(real path removed)/first-try-typescript>tsc --emitDecoratorMetadata --experimentalDecorators decorators.ts
decorators.ts(8,3): error TS1240: Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
```

I have tried everything from same stackoferflow questions suggestions:

- adding emitDecoratorMetadata & experimentalDecorators to tsconfig
- running tsc --emitDecoratorMetadata --experimentalDecorators
- adding `:any` to mark decorator function returning value
- adding `descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>` type

I always get this error. Both in a terminal and in Webstorm code hints. Method decorator - the same thing (see example below).

```
function test(target: Object,
              propertyKey: string,
              descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>): any {
  return descriptor;
}

class A {
  a: number = 1
  b: number = 2

  @test
  myMethod () {}
}

const a = new A()
```

Up to date code is here - https://github.com/rantiev/first-try-typescript

Comment: What is your desired result? A decorator should be applied to a function/method, what you are attempting to do seems to be mixing a method into a class

Comment: @NickTomlin -- That's incorrect, a decorator can be applied to a property as well.

Comment: @JohnWeisz ahh interesting, my bad then!

Comment: @JohnWeish - I have tried to do apply decorator for method - same results. See updated example.

I thought that it's ok to add prop decorators the way I did, based on this article https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841

Comment: Here is latest code https://github.com/rantiev/first-try-typescript

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, *property decorators* do not have access to the property descriptor, as properties live on the *class instance*, while decorators are evaluated before any instance could possibly exist. Also, you can only use the following signature for a property decorator:

```
function (target: any, propKey: string | symbol)
```

So no descriptor here.

You also can't just do `Object.defineProperty(target, propKey.toString, { enumerable: false, value: ... })` because that would be shared across all instances of your class, i.e. setting a property in one instance would leak into another.

Achieving what you are doing is possible though, but a bit complicated. What I generally do is *create a getter on the prototype that creates the desired property descriptor just in time*. Something like:

```
function enumerable(value: boolean) {
    return function (target: any, propKey: string | symbol) {
        Object.defineProperty(target, propKey, {
            get: function () {
                // In here, 'this' will refer to the class instance.
                Object.defineProperty(this, propKey.toString(), {
                    value: undefined,
                    enumerable: value
                });
            },
            set: function (setValue: any) {
                // In here, 'this' will refer to the class instance.
                Object.defineProperty(this, propKey.toString(), {
                    value: setValue,
                    enumerable: value
                });
            }
        });
    };
}
```

The "outer" get/set functionality will only run once, as the instance property will shadow it after the property descriptor has been created on the instance.

Comment: Your property decorator example works indeed. It seems it's too early to start using prop decorators. Working out the problem i have noticed information that property decorators not supported yet (seems there are some problems with them) and on other hand babel has no examples for using prop decorators as well https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-decorators/

Comment: But what should work - method decorator, doesn't work on my side with typescript, can't find the issue.

Comment: *"It seems it's too early to start using prop decorators. "* -- I wouldn't say so, you just need to understand their architectural limitations and the required workarounds. And as for a method decorator, what does _"doesn't work"_ mean? Nothing happens at runtime? Compile error?

Comment: As described in the question itself, compilation error. You can see it by yourself using my repository.